# Titanium.App.addEventListener executed twice (Titanium Studio)

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium-mobile, addeventlistener

I've a listener which executed twice.

When i fire event (oneEvent):

> Titanium.App.fireEvent('deleteUser');
>
> Ti.App.addEventListener('oneEvent',function(e){
>     doSomething();
>   });

doSomething executed twice.

Comment: that happens often for me, e.g a scroll event on a scrollable View fires 28 - 30 times when its been scrolled, you could check if it wfires in a minimum intervall and don't execute the callback function, but i think you can't really do sth for the firing of the event itself

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, this would just be guesses at what you did.  We need to see how the oneEvent if fired.

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you visit that window that event is add every time so that events are fire more then once if you visited window more then one time.

Answer (score 0):

`Titanium.App.fireEvent('deleteUser');` called in function in window1.js
and `Ti.App.addEventListener('oneEvent',function(e){ doSomething(); });` in window2.js